# How to find marklogic 9 installed data hub version using REST API

Tags: marklogic

How do I find, then query, the ML server REST API to give me the data hub version running on a MarkLogic 9 system on linux please?

I tried using **https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/tools/rest/rest-extensions.html**  but then realized I had no way to actually tell which TCP port on the server that the REST API was running on.

I can access port 8001 and see all the Admin, App-Services App Servers ( I am local admin on box ) but the ML doco seems to point to port 8001. But when I use the URL of   **https://localhost:8001/v1/resources/mlHubversion**  I get an error.

I'm a database guy, not a web dev, so you will need to be patient with me.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Admin ui, and look between the App Servers, there should most likely be one named 'data-hub-FINAL'. The default for that app server is usually port 8011. If you can find one named like that, and it is indeed running on port 8011, then you should be able to invoke the mlHubversion endpoint with:

http://localhost:8011/v1/resources/mlHubversion

Or maybe with https rather than http, if it is configured for SSL.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for the response - I checked it. On my personal  ML10 instance at home its all fine. But that URL doesn't seem to exist on our ML9 server at work and I just get a blank page returned. How would I tell where the v1/resources/mlHubversion is mounted please? Or is it possible the  /v1/resources/mlHubversion  has been turned off ?  When I go to https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/REST    , v1/resources/mlHubversion  isn't even listed, unless I'm looking in the wrong spot?

Comment: Did you check if the data-hub-FINAL app server is running on the port you expect it to run? It might be configured at a completely different port.

Comment: I discovered that ML10 supports this command, but ML9 apparently doesnt support it. So at least I know why now. Thanks for your help.